# Cannot Install xenial-backports

Tags: apt

I am trying to install xenial-backports:

```
sudo apt-get install -t xenial-backports
```

but I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'xenial-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not 
available in the sources
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post output from lsb_release -a and what happens if you do a apt-get clean and then apt-get update and then run install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the repository, not the package.

To add *xenial-backports* [repository section](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/) use the command below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports universe restricted multiverse main"
```

and then update packages lists by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Afterwards you will be able to install [available packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/allpackages) from it.